# Якорь используя class, а не id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Обычно ссылки на определенный блок привязаны через id. Можно ли как то сделать через class?

Comment: Средствами HTML - нельзя, а с помощью JS - можно, несколькими способами.

Comment: а как возможно сделать на js? есть какие то примеры?

Comment: @MaximLensky в вордпрессе секциям нельзя привязать id в редакторе Gutenberg, ищу решение..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097384/6339052

Comment: Как можно сделать - например, методами `scroll`, `scrollTo`; или изменяя значение `scrollTop` к X-координате элемента; или экзотически, смещением элементов в overflow-hidden контейнере; или даже банально добавляя сгенерированные `id` и `href`. Множество способов. Есть ли примеры - здесь я воздержусь от кода (т.к. вопрос вообще был "можно ли"... слишком невнятный/общий, а примеры будут конкретны. То есть, не хочется ни угадывать какой подойдет, ни писать целую книгу по всем возможным способам. Остальным участникам, видимо, тоже этого не хочется).

Comment: Ой, то есть _к **Y**-координате_, конечно же, если речь о вертикальной прокрутке. Прошу прощения.

Comment: @yar85, раз вы стесняетесь - оформил в ответ.

Comment: @qwabra, Если у нас разные мнения о "что лучше: некачественный ответ, или отсутствие ответа" - это не значит, что уместны вбросы типа «стесняешься». Извини если мое восприятие принципов SO возмущает или раздражает, совсем не хотел этого. А плюсик твоему ответу конечно поставлю (если суть коммента была в этом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPD

для полноценной эмуляции якоря, необходимо добавить прокрутку по хэшу в адресе страницы "sitename.com/page1#ClassName" (**#ClassName** - якорь).

для реализации необходимо получить якорь из адреса, например используя `location.hash`, и реализовать обработку и прокрутку при загрузке страницы.

### предостережение

элементов с одинаковым `class` name может быть несколько

### документация

- `scroll` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll
- `scrollTo` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo
- `scrollTop` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop
- `getBoundingClientRect` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
- `location.hash` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/location

### пример

```js
window.onload = () => {
 const C = document.getElementsByClassName('C')[0];
 const { left, top } = C.getBoundingClientRect()
 window.scroll(left, top)

 const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
 button.onclick = () => {
  window.scrollTo({
   left: 0,
   top: 0,
   behavior: 'smooth'
  })
 }
}
```

```css
div {
 position: relative;
 height: 2500px;
}
button {
 position: fixed;
 right: 18px;
 bottom: 25px;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="A"><h2>A</h2></div>
<div class="B"><h2>B</h2></div>
<div class="C"><h2>C</h2></div>
<div class="D"><h2>D</h2></div>

<button>T O P</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

После нажатия на ссылку, можно взять нужный элемент по классу, добавить ему временный id, добавить тот же id под href кликнутой ссылки... а когда браузер сделает свою работу, замести следы))

В примере у каждой ссылки своя пара:

```js
setClassHref("js-anchor", "js-target");

function setClassHref(anchorClass, targetClass) {
  let anchor = document.querySelectorAll('.' + anchorClass); // ссылки
  let target = document.querySelectorAll('.' + targetClass); // блоки

  let tempHref = "anchor-bubu"; // временное id
  let trueTargetId = null; // на всякий случай сохранить реальный id цели, если он есть.

  for (let i = 0; i < anchor.length; i++) {
    anchor[i].addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      this.setAttribute("href", "#" + tempHref);

      trueTargetId = target[i].id;
      target[i].id = tempHref;
    });

    anchor[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setAttribute("href", "JavaScript:void(0);");
        target[i].id = trueTargetId;
      }, 0); // Таймаут без таймера - сработает сразу после срабатывания href
    });
  }
}
```

```css
nav { position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="js-anchor">bubu-1</a>
  <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="js-anchor">bubu-2</a>
  <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="js-anchor">bubu-3</a>
</nav>

<div style="margin-top: 500px;" class="js-target">bubu-1</div>
<div style="margin-top: 500px;" class="js-target">bubu-2</div>
<div style="margin-top: 500px;" class="js-target">bubu-3</div>
```